# Plot ConvexHull in basemap

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I am making a ConvexHull in python, by a set of latitude and longitudinal positions. Then I want to plot the points, alongside the ConvexHull in a basemap. Everything works fine if I plot them in a normal plot without a map,as I follow the instructions from http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html#scipy.spatial.ConvexHull. When I try to plot them with a basemap, I just get the regular plot. What do I do wrong?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

map = Basemap(projection='merc',
    resolution = 'c', area_thresh = 40,
    llcrnrlon=27.72, llcrnrlat=69.41,
    urcrnrlon=28.416, urcrnrlat=70.95)
con = lite.connect(databasepath)
    with con: 
        cur = con.execute("SELECT DISTINCT latitude, longitude FROM MessageType1 where latitude>= 70.55 and latitude<= 70.7 and longitude >= 27.72 and longitude <= 28.416 limit 100 ")
        points = [[float(x[1]), float(x[0])]  for x in cur]
        points = np.array(points)
        hull = ConvexHull(points)

        x,y = map(points[:,0], points[:,1])
        plt.plot(x, y, 'o')
        for simplex in hull.simplices:
            x,y = map(points[simplex,0], points[simplex,1])
            plt.plot(x,y, 'k-')
        plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add some methods after setting up the Basemap to draw the map features.  Eg:

```
map.drawcoastlines()
map.drawstates()
map.drawcountries()
map.drawmapboundary()
```

See the documentation: http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/geography.html